# Broken background image on an SVG

Tags: html, svg

I've been asked to add a big SVG file into a .html page. It has a background image, but it doesn't show.

This is the line of code that concerns the background image:

```
<defs>
    <clipPath id="a">
        <path fill="none" d="M0 0h1920v1080H0z"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>
<g clip-path="url(#a)">
    <image width="1920" height="1080" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEpyP.png"/>
</g>
```

The link to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEpyP.png

The rest of the SVG shows just fine, but where the background should be, there is a large "broken image" icon that sits behind everything.

How do I get the background working here? I had it locally and have had `xlink:href="images/bg.png"` but the same broken image icon appears

Comment: I've putted your code inside an svg `<svg viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">...` element and everything seams OK

Comment: You need to convert the image to a data URL.